# ¿Qué es un error NoReserveMatch, y cómo hago para arreglarlo?

Tags: django, django-urls

Tengo algún código y cuando se ejecuta, lanza un NoReserveMatch, diciendo:

> Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 11}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Answer (score 1):

Este error aparece cuando la url esta mal o no tiene nada para retornar, en este caso aparentemente el objeto por el pk no existe, entonces no puede retornar la vista detallada para ese objeto. Si publicas tu view, y urls puedo ayudarte